# Importing excel data into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, excel

I need to import data from Excel to my database. I need to insert the data from my Excel sheet to an existing table in my database.

I tried to import data with the help of sql wizard. Firstly I imported it into a temp table then I used an insert query to import data into my destination table. But it does not seem to have worked correctly.

So, plz suggest me good way of importing the data. And also it would be better if you suggest some good sql script for importing.

Comment: How many columns are in the spreadsheet?

Comment: What do you mean by "some what not fine"? Did anything work?

Answer (score 3):

For file excel 2007 version (*.xlsx)

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\test.xlsx', [Customer$])
```

For file excel 97-2003 version (*.xls)

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\test.xls', [Customer$])
```

Comment: @AlirezaMassali [Customer$] is sheetname from file test.xls

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the previous answer on an `.xlsx` file (version 14.0.6112.2500 64-bit Microsoft Excel file)

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\xls_to_sql\xltest.xlsx', [Sheet1$])
```

I then saved the spreadsheet as an `.xls` (97-2003 version) and tried again.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\xls_to_sql\xltest.xls', [Sheet1$])
```

Bot times I got the same error message:

```
 Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
 OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.
```

SQL SERVER information:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.50.1617.0 Microsoft
>   Analysis Services Client Tools  10.50.1617.0 Microsoft Data Access
>   Components (MDAC)  6.1.7601.17514 Microsoft MSXML  2.6 3.0 6.0 
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer  9.0.8112.16421 Microsoft .NET Framework 
>   2.0.50727.5448 Operating System  6.1.7601

I don't have the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 or at least I don't know how to get it.  I also don't know how to run everything in 32-Bit mode if that is the cause of the problem.  I would appreciate help running in 32-Bit mode and also downloading and installing Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 if I don't have it installed for some reason.

I tried the linked server method I saw posted for SQL Server 2005 but there is no Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 option that was mentioned in the tutorial. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686.

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention anything about your existing table and keys in table and excel file, so just to give you a push, following command selects all data from xltest.xls file sheet ('customrs')

```
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [Customers$])
```

from this point, it's up to your database structure how to import/merge to existing data.

Answer (score 0):

first saved the spreadsheet as an .xls (97-2003 version) format and import them to SQL in temporary file. After import those data make sure that temp table field lengths are similar to original.

then use below statement to update orginal table

```
insert into orginal (field1, field2)
select field1, field2 from temp
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways I usually do this.

1. Use VBA inside the Worksheet. This involves some development work which imho is too much effort, if you are doing this only one time. This is nice if you want to use this worksheet multiple times.
2. Use a combination of macros inside the worksheet to concatenate
   insert queries which I then paste into SQL Management Studio, or
   some similar SQL client, and run the inserts.
3. Use the bulk copy command-line tool to copy a CSV file, which I
   would convert from the worksheet, like this:   `bcp
   [dbname].[dbo].[myTableName] in data1.csv -T -SmyServerName  -c -t^|
   > log1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import a .xlsx into 64-bit SQL Server, try installing the 64-bit Microsoft Access database Engine.

See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

For example, to import data from c:\data.xlsx, which has a sheet called MyData, then you could use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OPENROWSET ( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
                  , 'Excel 12.0;database=c:\data.xlsx;IMEX=1'
                  , 'SELECT * FROM [MyData$]')
```